# Android: how to get logs from device?

Tags: android

For test app I want to add feature gather data and send it via email. I google a lot and found only this approach:

```
    String cmd = String.format("logcat -d '%s:I' '*:S'", Schema.TAG);
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( 
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append(separator);
    }
```

But when I execute this command I get an empty string from inputstream.

Could you suggest how I can get a logs from device?

p.s. 
I want to avoud use a google analitycs